# Will TideSDK webkit version be upgraded?

Tags: webkit, tidesdk

I heard on StackOverflow the webkit version is about 2 years old.

Will you upgrade the webkit ?

Or can I upgrade it by myself ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substantive investment has been made primarily through the efforts of [CoastalForge Inc](http://coastalforge.com), a company founded by the core developers of TideSDK, to work on a solution and to deliver for the future of this technology.

To put this in perspective, WebKit is one of the largest code bases on the planet and app developers may not fully understand the efforts that have been underway for some time. There may be over 100 commits a day to WebKit and there are three versions of WebKit in the current product. Each presents its own challenges and requires patching to enable the scripting languages (python, php and ruby) we support to be evaluated. This runs deep in the core of our code (which itself is substantial and complex).

Advanced skill sets and considerable time is required for successful analysis and programming. Beyond human resources, properly equipped systems with appropriate tool chains are required. Compilation of WebKit is itself approximately 4hrs when everything is right. We use specially equipped machines to attempt to reduce compile cycles.

Assuredly, WebKit has been receiving considerable attention over a great deal of time. We've also been evaluating the upgraded code on the platforms we support. An announcement is on the way soon about how the work will be rolled out. You can look forward to this in the near future. We are aware of the critical need of the highest levels of HTML5 compliance for anyone investing in this technology. We are certain what we will be releasing is going to welcomed.